# Running `.dart` files does not show logging messages

Tags: dart

I just cannot figure out how to show logging messages when running dart files from terminal.

#### Example `example.dart`:

```dart
import 'dart:developer';

void main() {
  print('print');
  log('log');
}
```

###### Expected output:

> print

> log

###### Actual output:

> print

I tried calling `dart example.dart`, `dart run --all example.dart`, `dart run --verbosity=all example.dart`, and different values instead of `all` (`info`, ...).

But non of these produced any helpful error messages let alone the out print I expect.

Answer (score 1):

[APIs from `dart:developer`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-developer/dart-developer-library.html) (such as `log`) are intended to interact with debugging tools:

> Interact with developer tools such as the debugger and inspector.

It's not explicit from [the documentation for `log`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-developer/log.html), but I'd expect it to send a log message *only* to an attached debugger, not to the console.

If you want logging output that is independent of a debugger, use [`package:logging`](https://pub.dev/packages/logging) and add a listener that calls `print`, as shown by the example.